# Why are my Baked Textures having Bad Results?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

I'm baking a normal map and a roughness map to use on my .obj that will be used in a AR application. Both normal and roughness were created procedurally (using noise texture node and bump). When using the this setup of node, everything looks good as you can see in the images bellow (look at the creases):
[image]

I've baked in a 2K image and the bakings itselves are looking fine, I'm not sure, as you can see here:

- NormalMap
  [image]
- RoughnessMap
  [image]

But when I use the baked images on the final object that will be exported, it doesn't look like the first model. The normals and the roughness are a bit strange. As you can see here:
[image]

What am I doing wrong ? Why does it not work properly ?

I was expecting the final results to be like that, similar to the model before applying the baked textures:
[image]

And not like this:

[image]

I'm not baking a high poly to a low poly object, I'm just baking to have my informations of normals, roughness and diffuse, as image textures one with my normals and another one with my roughness on it (and the diffuse, but this one is ok).

[image]

Comment: When creating the images to bake to, did you initialize your `normal map` with `alpha` disabled and `32-bit float` enabled? That is the only possible solution I can think of after looking at your `.blend` file. I might just have to pass the problem off to someone more experienced. Also, it would be really helpful to have your procedural nodes in the `.blend` file. If you could update it to have that, it would be alot easier to work out whats wrong

Comment: Actually, when talking about the normal map, I created a file with the alfa on, and the 32-bit float disabled.

Sure! I will do that!

Comment: @Gunt.r I've uploaded a new file, with my procedural nodes as well. There are two materials there. One is the material before the baking (procedural one) and the other is the baked one.

Comment: Sorry man I literally got no clue. I'm going to have to pass the problem off to the pros. For whoever is going to pick up the problem: I dont think the normals have anything to do with the problem. Also, the texture resolution being too low is not the problem. I have tried rendering bakes at 4k instead of 2k and it didnt work

Comment: @Gunt.r What should be the difference when initializing the image with alpha disabled or enabled and with 32-bit float enabled or disabled? Beyond having the transparent background. To me it really didn't make any difference.

Comment: to be completely honest man I really don't know. A person who I was watching in a tutorial said alpha had to be disabled and 32 bit float enabled for the bake to work. I'm just doing that because that has been the way i've been taught.

Answer (score 1):

When you make an image texture for roughness and normal you have to switch color space from srgb to non color data before you bake.

Comment: in both cases?
Do I have to use them as non color when using the image based texture too ?? I though I could use the roughness as Raw or sRGB.

Comment: any texture that does not contribute to the color of the object must be set to non color data roughness, specular, subsurface scattering, normal, transmission and such must be non color data (NCD). Most of those textures named above are black and white but normal map for instance is colored, dont let this confuse you normal still has to be NCD  since it does not contribute to color of the object. So any texture that has to be NCD when it is being used normally must also be set to NCD when you are baking them. also when you bake an image you cant change color space after you must make new image